# Is (fmap f) the same as (f .) if f is a function of type a->b?

Tags: haskell, functor

I am trying to implement a Functor instance of

```
data ComplicatedA a b
    = Con1 a b
    | Con2 [Maybe (a -> b)]
```

For Con2, my thought process was the fmap needs to be something like

```
fmap f (Con2 xs) = Con2 (map f' xs)
```

then I need to have a list map function f' like

```
Maybe (a -> x) -> Maybe (a -> y)
```

Since `Maybe` is a Functor, I can write f' like

```
fmap ((a->x) -> (a->y))
```

In order to get `((a->x) -> (a->y))`, I thought I could just do 
`fmap (x->y)` which is the same as `(fmap f)`

So my sulotion was

```
instance Functor (ComplicatedA a) where
    fmap f (Con1 x y) = Con1 x (f y)
    fmap f (Con2 xs) = Con2 (map (fmap (fmap f)) xs)
```

However the real solution uses `(f .)` instead of `(fmap f)` to get `((a->x) -> (a->y))` from `x -> y` and it looks like this

```
instance Functor (ComplicatedA a) where
    fmap f (Con1 a b) = Con1 a (f b)
    fmap f (Con2 l) = Con2 (map (fmap (f .)) l)
```

I was just wondering what the problem was with my thought process and solution. Is (fmap f) the same as (f .) if f is a function of type a->b?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `fmap f` is indeed the same as `(f .)` if the functor being talked about is functions (`(->) r` as it's usually denoted).

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks. So is my solution also correct?

Comment: I believe so, yes. (But I'm not an expert and don't have time right now to check in detail.)

Comment: They are both correct indeed (cc @RobinZigmond).

Comment: ...and you can even replace `map` with `fmap` to make it funnier to read. `fmap f (Con2 l) = Con2 (fmap (fmap (fmap f)) l)`. And then decide it would be even funnier with more `fmap`s, and that `fmap (fmap (fmap f))` is `fmap . fmap . fmap $ f`, and that `(.)` is `fmap`, so `Con2 (fmap fmap (fmap fmap fmap) f l)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I don't think you've gone far enough. I'm pretty sure it's possible to write `fmap f (Con2 l) = fmap fmap ... fmap Con2 fmap fmap ... fmap f l` where the first batch of `fmap`s is extremely long, and I believe the second batch is fairly short. It would be interesting to calculate how many are required.

Comment: @DanielWagner, actually ... that will end up so enormous that there's little chance it could be compiled. But you can definitely add a lot more `fmap`s.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I've [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566397/how-many-fmaps-does-it-take) about this.

Comment: For fun, you can let the predefined notion of functor composition do this for you. From `Data.Functor.Compose`, the newtype `Compose` has a functor instance. `fmap f (Con2 l) = Con2 . getCompose . getCompose . fmap f . Compose . Compose $ l`

Comment: @klabe In my opinion, not only you solution is correct, but is also more readable than the other. You essentially need to "lift" `f :: b->b'` through two functors, `a ->` and `Maybe`, so using two `fmap`s feels very natural to me. I would also like `fmap (fmap (fmap f))`, since `[]` is a third functor. (Of course, the simplest is to write `deriving Functor` and let GHC do it for us, but writing functor instances by hand is very useful to learn how functor work)

Comment: @DanielWagner, you disproved my conjecture, but you can still write `fmap f (Con2 l) = Con2 $ fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap f l`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solutions are indeed equivalent. [`fmap` for the function/reader functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-818) is `(.)`:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

(`(->) r` is the function type constructor being used with prefix syntax -- `(->) r a` is the same as `r -> a`.)

The intuition is that, as you have noted, `(.) :: (x -> y) -> (a -> x) -> (a -> y)` uses a `x -> y` function to modify the results of an `a -> x` function.

Comment: I wish the syntax `(r ->)` were allowed, since I’ve seen people misread `(->) r` as a function *to* `r` instead of *from* —trouble is, it suggests `(-> r)` would be allowed, which it can’t be, since it’d affect decidability of unification for higher-kinded types. Whomp.

Comment: That would be helpful indeed, @JonPurdy