# How many fmaps does it take?

Tags: haskell

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564018/is-fmap-f-the-same-as-f-if-f-is-a-function-of-type-a-b#comment97828453_55564018) by Daniel Wagner led me to this question. Let's start with an over-simplification. Suppose you have a type

```
data Foo a = Foo [a]
```

Then you can write the `Functor` instance

```
instance Functor Foo where
  fmap f (Foo l) = Foo (fmap f l)
```

You can rewrite the right hand side as

```
Foo . fmap f $ l
```

Recognizing that for `(->) a`, `fmap = (.)`, you can write it

```
fmap Foo (fmap f) l
```

Repeating, you get

```
fmap (fmap Foo) fmap f l
```

And so, finally,

```
fmap f (Foo l) =
  fmap fmap fmap Foo fmap f l
```

---

What if you pick a slightly more complex functor?

```
data Bar = Bar [Maybe a]

instance Functor Bar where
  fmap f (Bar l) = Bar (fmap (fmap f) l)
```

I started doing this by hand, but it started to get out of control, so I switched to automatic.

```
infixl 9 :@
data Expr
  = BAR | F | L | FMap | Expr :@ Expr
  deriving (Show)

rewrite :: Expr -> Expr
rewrite (p :@ (q :@ r))
  = rewrite $ FMap :@ p :@ q :@ r
rewrite (p :@ q) = rewrite p :@ q
rewrite e = e

main = print $ rewrite $
  BAR :@ (FMap :@ (FMap :@ F) :@ L)
```

Unfortunately, this seems to produce an utterly enormous result. I couldn't even calculate the leftmost leaf of the tree in a reasonable amount of time. Just how big an expression does this make? How quickly does it grow as more functors are layered on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infinite. The following term loops your rewriter:

```
FMap :@ ((FMap :@ (FMap :@ FMap)) :@ FMap)
```

It does so in just three steps, which are:

```
((FMap :@ FMap) :@ (FMap :@ (FMap :@ FMap))) :@ FMap
(((FMap :@ (FMap :@ FMap)) :@ FMap) :@ (FMap :@ FMap)) :@ FMap
(((FMap :@ ((FMap :@ (FMap :@ FMap)) :@ FMap)) :@ FMap) :@ FMap) :@ FMap
```

This last has the original term at its head. (The original looping term itself arises after six steps of rewriting your `BAR :@ (FMap :@ (FMap :@ F) :@ L)`.)